# Insert a mark at specified position at the external margin

Tags: margins, rules

I want to insert a rule in an exact position (2.4 in from the top, for instance) at the external margin of a given page interval (from page 2 to 4, or bigger). I don't have any idea how to do it, but I am using the geometry package to define the margins.

Is something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can a hook in the page shipout to add something at a fixed position (packages such as `everyshi` provide similiar features if you have an older LaTex without `\AddToHook`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}
          {\put(\paperwidth,-2in){\line(-1,0){.5in}}}


\begin{document}

zz
\end{document}
```